# c# WinForms ListView Grouping by Selection

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, user-interface

I have a ListView which has Checked = true and two groups (Selected and Not Selected). On Checked I wish to move the Item to the appropriate group but it seems that moving the Group causes ItemChecked event to trigger again.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.ItemChecked += listView1_ItemChecked;
}

private void listView1_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
    {
        if (item.Checked && item.Group != listView1.Groups["grpSelected"])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Checked = true [1] : " + item.Text);
            item.Group = listView1.Groups["grpSelected"];
            Console.WriteLine("Checked = true [2] : " + item.Text);
            break;
        }
        if (!item.Checked && item.Group != listView1.Groups["grpNotSelected"])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Checked = false [1] : " + item.Text);
            item.Group = listView1.Groups["grpNotSelected"];
            Console.WriteLine("Checked = false [2] : " + item.Text);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The result in Output for going from Checked --> !Checked

```
Checked = false [1] : test0
Checked = true [1] : test0
Checked = true [2] : test0
Checked = false [2] : test0
```

Is there a better way to get this feature? Or a way around the problem? Currently I need to double click to get the desired effect but it is very much ugly!

## EDIT

This worked but also seems wrong...

```
private void listView1_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
{
    listView1.ItemChecked -= listView1_ItemChecked;
    foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
    {
        if (item.Checked && item.Group != listView1.Groups["grpSelected"])
        {
            item.Group = listView1.Groups["grpSelected"];
            item.Checked = true;
            break;
        }
        if (!item.Checked && item.Group != listView1.Groups["grpNotSelected"])
        {
            item.Group = listView1.Groups["grpNotSelected"];
            item.Checked = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    listView1.ItemChecked += listView1_ItemChecked;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//Suppose the first Group is Checked, the second Group is Unchecked    
//ItemCheck event handler for your listView1
private void listView1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e){
   listView1.Items[e.Index].Group = listView1.Groups[e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked ? 0 : 1];
}
//you need to do this initially to group your items correctly
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
     item.Group = listView1.Groups[item.Checked ? 0 : 1];
```

Comment: Tried `listView1.Items[e.Item.Index].Group = listView1.Groups[e.Item.Checked ? 0 : 1];` but still the same issue

Comment: @rjinski have you **registered** `ItemCheck` event handler for your `listbox`? BTW, **I tested this**, I'm not such a pro writing this in moment.

Comment: @rjinski you have to remove your code, don't use your code simultaneously with my code.

Comment: I overlooked this was ItemCheck and not ItemChecked - worked a treat! Thank you!!